# Accidentally activated two autocomplete packages in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete

I'm relatively new to emacs and somehow activated to different auto-complete packages (see image). I know that one is due to jedi, which I need for python scripting and latex and I believe jedi causes the grey menu. Can someone tell me how to deactivate the orange one?

[example of two menus with auto-complete suggestions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4dhS.png)

Comment: you can interactively de/activate modes with `M-x <name-of-mode>`. Two popular completion packages are `company-mode` (possibly the bottom?) and `auto-complete-mode` (possibly the top)

Comment: It's exactly like you said. I deactivated company-mode and the orange menu is gone, thank you very much!